# Cannot login as any user other than root - no error message

Tags: linux, root, raspbian

I'm sure it's something very simple, once you know where to look.

This is happening on an Orange Pi PC v1.2, running Raspbian, as it is distributed by [orangepi.org](http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/%20orangepi). I can't login as any user except root.

I have added a couple of users with `adduser`, and I cannot use any from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> consoles, nor via `su`, nor via `ssh`.

(I have added the public keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` in order to avoid so much typing).

`su`? No:

```
root@orangepi:~# su mario
root@orangepi:~#
```

`ssh`? No:

```
mario@rune:~$ ssh mario@orangepi
Linux orangepi 3.4.39 #41 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 21 13:09:26 HKT 2015 armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Mar 23 08:51:43 2016 from rune.lan
```

Then, instead of the expected prompt: `mario@orangepi:~$`

I get logged out: `Connection to orangepi closed.`

The `Last login` timestamp gets updated at any attempt, meaning I do get logged in, but something logs me out immediately after.

To be sure, this is what I have in my `/etc/passwd`:

```
root@orangepi:~# grep mario /etc/passwd
mario:x:1002:1006:Mario Frasca,,,:/home/mario:/bin/bash
root@orangepi:~# ls -ld /home/mario
drwxr-xr-x 3 mario mario 4096 Mar 23 08:36 /home/mario
root@orangepi:~# ls -ld /bin/bash 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 813992 Sep 25  2014 /bin/bash
root@orangepi:~#
```

If I log in as root, all goes as expected (I get in the box).

---

Later test (using numeric address for `orangepi` box):

```
mario@rune:~$ ssh mario@192.168.1.107 ls -m
mario@rune:~$ ssh root@192.168.1.107 ls -m ~mario
pistore.desktop
mario@rune:~$
```

---

All these `ssh mario@orangepi` are consistently logged in `/var/log/auth.log` as:

```
Mar 24 09:47:16 localhost sshd[2987]: Accepted publickey for mario from 192.168.1.89 port 40695 ssh2
Mar 24 09:47:16 localhost sshd[2987]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mario by (uid=0)
Mar 24 09:47:16 localhost sshd[2989]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.89: 11: disconnected by user
Mar 24 09:47:16 localhost sshd[2987]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mario
```

---

I also checked if it could be some `pam` configuration trouble:

```
root@orangepi:~# pam_tally2 -u mario
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
mario               0    
root@orangepi:~#
```

---

I later decided I would not use Raspbian and installed Lubuntu, where things work fine, but I'm left with the question, what's wrong with the Orange Pi Raspbian image?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be fixed by executing this command

```
echo "vm.mmap_min_addr = 4096" >  /etc/sysctl.d/mmap_min_addr.conf
```

And reboot. I do not know why, but it works.

Source - [Orange Pi Forum](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=224&extra=&page=1)

Comment: thank you for the hint, I cannot confirm at the moment so I can't mark this as accepted. if I ever go back to raspbian, I will try your hint and if it does work, I will accept the answer. :-)

Comment: After the first reboot I got only black screen with a mouse cursor. Apparently, it was an autologin as the 'orangepi' user with bare openbox, nothing is broken now. To get a nice gui I just needed to logout/login to LXDE.